# UIImage IBAction Segue?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want to make a IBAction segue when i tap a simple image on my app. I don't want to use nav controllers I just want to be able to hit the button and slide to a new view with the option to slide back via a new control on the new view. I know the code is simple I was wondering if anyone had it on deck at the moment...

to the 5 people that obviously don't know the answer to my question;

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
[self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:animated];
[super viewWillAppear:animated];
}

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
[self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:animated];
[super viewWillDisappear:animated];
}
```

Put this above the did load method in / the m file 'mkay?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use remove all the subviews and attach new subviews if you really don't want to use `UINavigationController`, but I advise against it. You can use navigation controller without exposing anything to the user. They don't have to know you're using one.

If you want to attach actions to an image, it's better to use `UIButton` with custom type and add a backgroundImage on the button.

Comment: Thank you. update in progress

Comment: I used the old way; add a uibutton, go to editor > embed in > navigation controller...then i added a new view to the storyboard from the object library, then lastly, i control clicked the button and dragged it to the view control scene on the left of the screen and selected push > segue action or what ever it is...

Comment: Hey Enrico Susatyo , how do you hide the navigation controller though?? thanks

Comment: You don't embed your `UIButton` in navigation controller, you hook up an action that pushes another view controller in your navigation controller stack. You hide the navigation bar by using `setNavigationBarHidden:YES`. But I think you will need to revisit a lot of navigation controller fundamentals.

Comment: thanks for the code. yes of course...i don't even think its possible to put a button directly in a navigation controller..thanks though!

Comment: any advice for getting the setNavigationBarHidden line to work? I threw it in the did load method but no avail; rest assured the nav control segue is working; thnx